# ::std::pair in a variadic function template

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to write a variadic function template, accepting `::std::pair`s, without having to construct the pairs manually:

```
void print_pairs()
{
}

template <typename ...B>
void print_pairs(::std::pair<int, int> const& a, B&&... b)
{
  ::std::cout << a.first << " " << a.second << ::std::endl;

  print_pairs(::std::forward<B>(b)...);
}
```

But I'd like to be able to write `print_pairs({1, 1}, {2, 2});`, instead of having to use `::std::make_pair` all the time.

EDIT:

After some thinking, the best solution might be the old school:

```
print_pairs(::std::pair<int, int> const&);
print_pairs(::std::pair<int, int> const&, ::std::pair<int, int> const&);
print_pairs(::std::pair<int, int> const&, ::std::pair<int, int> const&, ::std::pair<int, int> const&);
```

and so on...

Comment: What's wrong with `initializer_list`?

Comment: If at all possible, I avoid it. Too much overhead for my taste.

Comment: Forgive me, but I've never heard of it having overhead.

Comment: Even if it did not have overhead, it is not relevant here.

Comment: You need to explain either how `initializer_list` has too much overhead, or how it is irrelevant. Otherwise, that is the solution to your problem.

Comment: Question is mistagged. Instead of [tag:c++] [tag:c++11] it should be [tag:just-some-arbitrary-subset-of-c++11]. And in that I am not interested.

Comment: Even if variadic template solution is less optimal than using `initializer_list`, I'd like to see it, please.

Comment: Another problem is that you can't have arbitrary types as non-type template parameters. For `print({1,1}, {2,3})` syntax to work with variadics, you'd need to be able to write something like `template<pair...Ps> print(Ps...ps);`

Comment: @user1095108, so `initializer_list` introduces some weird **irrelevant**, *not proved* overhead? I am sorry, I am entirely lost by your "logic".

Comment: Folks, please, I mentioned overhead only in the comments, it is not part of my question.

Comment: It's the only rationale you've given for the strange premise of this question. It's relevant.

Comment: This is exactly why we need the "too localized" close reason back.

Comment: You don't have to use `make_pair` all the time: `using P = std::pair<int,int>; print_pairs( P{1,1}, P{2,2}, P{3,3} );`

Comment: Indeed. OP seems to think SO is for him. It is not. It is a database of meaningful programming questions that help x people where x>1.

Comment: If you like, I can delete the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it rules out the most obvious answer by saying "I don't like using std::initializer_list"

Comment: @JonathanWakely You forget the other solution, given by jrok.

Comment: Before you get around this "the standard library is slow" non-sense-conviction, the better. Especially for you. I used to be affected by it too, but then I fought my fears and now I'm in a happy relationship with it. It's gonna be 2 years the next month.

Comment: @user1095108, we want you to learn to ask smart questions. Your question is like "how can I put a nail in my wall? I don't like hammers, so they are out of the question". It's not a smart question. A hammer is a tool designed to hammer the nails (well, at least the original kinds of hammers). `std::initializer_list` is designed for this thing you want. Let me repeat: "I don't like hammers" is the most stupid thing you can say when asking about hammering (sic!) your nails into your wall.

Comment: Why does the obfuscated `C` contest exist then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to print two numbers per line, why bother constructing the `std::pair`s at all?

```
void print_pairs()
{
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Rest>
void print_pairs(const T& a, const U& b, const Rest&... rest)
{
    std::cout << a << " " << b << '\n';
    print_pairs(rest...);
}

int main()
{
    print_pairs(1, 1,  2, 2);
}
```

If you really need the pairs, just create them inside the function template:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename... Rest>
void print_pairs(T&& a, U&& b, Rest&&... rest)
{
    auto p = std::make_pair(std::forward<T>(a), std::forward<U>(b));
    // ...
    print_pairs(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
}
```

Comment: I believe the body of the function is irrelevant and was just a simple example.

Comment: @Rapptz Is there something that you can do with a `std::pair` but  can't with a pair of integers?

Comment: exactly, and I wanted to use `pair` to prevent errors, that is, an odd number of arguments.

Comment: @jrok using them in a map, logical comparisons e.g. `std::make_pair(a, b) < std::make_pair(c, d);` etc.

Comment: Exactly. You can always use `make_pair` inside the function :/

Comment: @user1095108 The above solution will give you a compile-time error for passing an odd number of arguments. No need for pairs.

Comment: @jrok I like your templated pair better, if you like, you can post an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @user1095108 Or add `static_assert(!(sizeof...(Rest) % 2), "...");` to Fred's original solution to error out on odd number of arguments.

Comment: @user1095108 You misread my comment. I was just showing what you *can't* do.

Comment: @Praetorian Why the `static_assert`? The compiler already rejects any call with an odd number of arguments: `error: no matching function for call to ‘print_pairs(int)’`

Comment: @jrok I posed a solution, based on your comment.

Comment: @Fred It does, but the error message with the `static_assert` could mention something about requiring an even number of arguments - arguably more user friendly than the compiler saying it failed to find a match for `print_pairs`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `jrok`, here's another solution:

```
template <int a, int b>
struct cpair
{
  static constexpr auto const first = a;
  static constexpr auto const second = b;
};

template <typename ...A>
void print_pairs()
{
  ::std::initializer_list<int>{(::std::cout << A::first << " " << A::second, 0)...};
}
```

This should work without much overhead.

Comment: It's funny how concerned you are with the *overhead* of passing around a pair of ints!

Comment: not a pair, but pairs and I am concerned about possible errors also.